# Understanding the "tail -f in python"

Tags: python, file-io, file, tail

I have created a very simple python script:

```
def read_then_follow(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(1.0)
            continue
        yield line

for line in read_then_follow("some_file.txt"): print line
```

The file "some_file.txt" contains a few lines of text, which will be written to screen when I run the script. If I then add a line to the file with `echo "line" >> some_file.txt`, the line will be printed to the screen within 1 second. But: if I open the file in *vim*, add a line at the bottom and save, the script stops to function. It neither writes the new line written in *vim* to screen nor respons to further `echo ...` commands.

For your information, I am currently using python 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(I'm assuming you are on some Unix-like operating system.)

Saving in vim will actually create a *new* file with the same name on the disk.  The file handle held by your script still points to the *old* file, which does not have a directory entry anymore.  If your script terminates, the reference counter of the old file will drop to 0 and the file will be removed.

Comment: Ah, that seems lke a very reasonable explanation. Thank you!

Comment: You can look at [:help crontab](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#crontab) in Vim for some information on the subject. This is the same issue.