# Automatically stop "tail -f catalina.out" when exception found or server is running

Tags: java, python, shell, tail

I have set up an automated deployment script (in shell script) for my web application.

It uses java, tomcat, maven and a postgres database.

The deployment script does this:

1. builds the deployable application from source repository
2. stops tomcat
3. applies database migration patches
4. deploys the war files in tomcat
5. starts tomcat (by invoking $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh)
6. exits with a success message

It's all working and it's pretty neat - but it needs a little improvement.
You see, even though it exits with a success message, sometimes the deploy was not successful because the web application did not start correctly.

I would like to refactor steps 5 and 6 so that after bring up the tomcat server, the deployment script would "tail -f" in the catalina.out file, looking either for a "server started successfully" message or an exception stack trace.

The tail -f output up to that point should be part of the output of the deployment script, and step 6 would "exit 0" or "exit 1" accordingly.

I know that should be possible, if not in shell script, maybe with python.
The problem is I'm a java specialist - and by specialist I mean I suck at everything else :-)

Help please? :-)

Comment: Look at Python's [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: As far as I know you might want to `tail -f` the localhost.<today>.log, some exceptions go there instead of catalina.out. It's true for my environment, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `tail -f` basically runs an endless loop on the file, should the script just `exec` that on success or do you mean just `tail` and exit successfully?

Comment: While Popen can be used to scan the output of `tail -f` it may be easier to just use python's file access functions like for example here: [tail-f-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326405/understanding-the-tail-f-in-python)

Comment: Thanks snies. That solved it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417962/stop-reading-process-output-in-python-without-hang)

Comment: I'll come back later to post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a solution using Python's subprocess.Popen, as suggested by @snies.

Here's what it looks like:

**waitForIt.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

def main(argv):
    filename = argv[1]
    match=argv[2]
    p = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-n', '0', '-f', filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True :
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        print line ,
        if match in line :
            break
    p.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

**tailUntil.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

filename=$1
match=$2

thisdir=$(dirname $0)
python $thisdir/waitForIt.py "$filename" "$match"
```

and then

**startTomcat.sh**

```
${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/startup.sh
logDeploy.sh "Agora vamos dar um tail no catalina.out..."
util_tailUntil.sh "$TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out" 'INFO: Server startup in '
```

It doesn't do what I originally intended (it still exits with return code 0 even when there is a stacktrace - but that could be changed with a little bit more of Python magic),
but all of tomcat's initialization log is part of the automated deploy out (and easily viewable on Jenkins' deploy job) - 
so that's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
tmp=$(mktemp -t catalina.XXXXXXX) || exit 136
trap 'rm "$tmp"' 0
trap 'exit 255' 2 15
tail -n 200 catalina.out >"$tmp"
if grep -q error "$tmp"; then
    cat "$tmp"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

On the other hand, if `startup.sh` were competently coded, you could just

```
if startup.sh; then
    tail -f catalina.out
else
    exit $?
fi
```

which can be shortened to

```
startup.sh || exit $?
tail -f catalina.out
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm lacking the shell script knownledge to understand what that first script is supposed to do :-)

Comment: It extracts the last 200 lines (rather arbitrary number, season to taste) and greps for an error message in them.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might want to take a look at the [Apache Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) application. It supports, amongst other things:

- Deploying applications remotely, and from local paths
- Listing currently deployed applications
- Reloading existing applications
- Starting an existing application
- Stopping an existing application
- Undeploying an existing application

The manager provides a web interface that can be called via `curl`, and which returns simple, parseable messages to indicate the status of the invoked command. Management functions can also be invoked via JMX, or Ant scripts. All in all, a very handy tool.